# Explicit solution of $\kappa^2u''-f(u)=0$ with certain boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Let $f(x) = -x+\frac18\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ and $F(x)$ be its primitive, i.e.,
$$
F(x) = -\frac12 x^2 +\frac18 [(1+x)\ln(1+x)+(1-x)\ln(1-x)].
$$
Let $M\in (0,1)$ be the unique zero point of $f(x)$.
I wonder if it is possible to derive the explicit solution of the following problem
$$
\begin{cases}
  \kappa^2 u'' - f(u) = 0, \\
  u(0)=u'(\frac{\pi}{2})=0,\ u(\frac{\pi}{2})=M,
\end{cases}
$$
where $\kappa>0$ is a constant.
Multiplying the equation by $u'$ and integrating from $x$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, we see
$$
u'(x) = \frac{\sqrt2}{\kappa} \sqrt{F(u(x) - F(M))}.
$$
By separation of variables and integrating, we get
$$
\int_0^u \frac{dw}{\sqrt{F(w)-F(M)}} = \int_0^x \frac{\sqrt2}{\kappa} ds = \frac{\sqrt2}{\kappa}x.
$$
However, it seems hard to compute the left-hand side integration. Does anyone know how to deal with this kind of integration or any reference about this?